# Vertically scrolling hubtile

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a 4x2 hub tile in my pivot app that does not scroll vertically. I've tried to add `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` in PivotItem and in the Grid container but cannot scroll. How can I add a vertical scroll?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap them with a ScrollViewer. Just wrap your Grid with a ScrollViewer and that should do.